# Recording is too long dbf file

Tags: c#, dbf

I am developing a small project to convert a `.CSV` file into a `.DBF` file.

It works fine however when I exceed 40 columns in my table I get this error :

> Recording is too long

After a lot of research I could see that `.DBF` files have limitations however column limitation is 256. So my query should be able to work normally.

There is my code :

```
int i2 = 0;
string createSql = "create table " + fileName + " (";

foreach (DataColumn dc in dataSet.Tables[0].Columns)
{
    string fieldName = dc.ColumnName;

    string type = dc.DataType.ToString();

    createSql = createSql + "[" + fieldName + "]" + " varchar(100),";
    i2++;

    list.Add(fieldName);
}

Console.WriteLine("NB COL : " + i2);
createSql = createSql.Substring(0, createSql.Length - 1) + ")";

OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(GetConnection(path));

OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
cmd.Connection = con;

con.Open();

cmd.CommandText = createSql;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

There is my code (Connection Oledb) :

```
private static string GetConnection(string path)
{
    return "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=dBASE IV;";
}
```

There is my query (Create Table) :

```
create table CSF 
(
     [NUMBER] varchar(100),
     [TYPE] varchar(100),
     [NAME1] varchar(100),
     [NAME2] varchar(100),
     [CIVNAME1] varchar(100),
     [CIVNAME2] varchar(100),
     [ADRESS1] varchar(100),
     [ADRESS2] varchar(100),
     [VATCAT] varchar(100),
     [COUNTRY] varchar(100),
     [VATNUMBER] varchar(100),
     [PAYCODE] varchar(100),
     [TELLNUMBER] varchar(100),
     [FAXNUMBER] varchar(100),
     [BNKACCNT] varchar(100),
     [ZIPCODE] varchar(100),
     [CITY] varchar(100),
     [DEFLTPOST] varchar(100),
     [LANG] varchar(100),
     [CATEGORY] varchar(100),
     [CENTRAL] varchar(100),
     [VATCODE] varchar(100),
     [CURRENCY] varchar(100),
     [LASTREMLEV] varchar(100),
     [LASTREMDAT] varchar(100),
     [TOTDEB1] varchar(100),
     [TOTCRE1] varchar(100),
     [TOTDEBTMP1] varchar(100),
     [TOTCRETMP1] varchar(100),
     [TOTDEB2] varchar(100),
     [TOTCRE2] varchar(100),
     [TOTDEBTMP2] varchar(100),
     [TOTCRETMP2] varchar(100),
     [ISLOCKED] varchar(100),
     [MEMOTYPE] varchar(100),
     [ISDOC] varchar(100),
     [F28150] varchar(100),
     [WBMODIFIED] varchar(100),
     [IBANAUTO] varchar(100),
     [BICAUTO] varchar(100),
     [EREMINDERS] varchar(100),
     [EMAIL] varchar(100)
)
```

I found these on the internet : [limit dbf](https://www.dbase.com/Knowledgebase/faq/dBASE_Limits_FAQ.html) but when I look I don't go over the limit : /

I have exactly 315 characters with all the columns
If you have any idea it would help me well :D

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: You shouldn't just make every column `VARCHAR(100)` - use the **most appropriate** datatype - always !! E.g. why is a column called `NUMBER` a `VARCHAR(100)` ? Why are yes/no flags like `IsDoc` or `IsLocked` `VARCHAR(100)` ?? Why are values that are most likely numeric like `TOTDEB` and `TOTCRE` all also `VARCHAR(100)` ?!?!?!? Seriously: use the **datatypes** that your database offers you! `NUMBER` or `INTEGER` or `DECIMAL` for numeric types, `BIT` or `BOOL` or whatever your database has to offer for flags etc. ....

Comment: You exceed 4000 bytes per row limitation.

Comment: I was having a similar problem with some access databases. There is also a limit of how many columns a table can have. The problem was, that when the table had lets say 50 columns and then i deleted 10 of these columns and recreated them, the count was now on 60. So it was more like a limit of how many columns you can create for one table and not how many columns there could exist simultaneously. Maybe you encounter a similar  problem here. In access I had to use the "compact and repair" function, which seems to reset the count to the actual count of columns.

Comment: I put the appropriate data types but just for the example I left everything in varchar which has no impact on my problem. Moreover the name of columns is due to a bad base creation which I am not at the origin and which I cannot do anything about.
How to force this row limitation ?
Not the similar problem :/
I delete the file and create it after each launch of my application.
Thank's for yours answers ! :D

Comment: You probably have a driver issue with the dbf connection.   What driver are you using?  Is it the latest?  If you are using the Jet for the dbf driver I would switch to an IBM driver.  See : https://www.connectionstrings.com/ibm-db2/